# Getting an error while using TinyMCE & WordPress: 'c is not a function'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I am using the tinyMCE plugin with Wordpress to turn a textarea (located in the backend) into a formatted HTML area.

Here is my code at the moment, which adds a class to the textarea then tries to target it with tinyMCE but not successfully.

```
    function add_class_to_textarea() {
      if(is_admin()) {
        echo '<script>var d = document.querySelector(".type-_textarea textarea");';
        echo 'd.className += "submissionText";</script>';

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
          echo 'tinymce.init({';
            echo 'selector: ".submissionText",';
            echo 'theme: "modern",';
            echo 'toolbar: false';
          echo '});';
        echo '</script>';
      }
    }
    add_action('admin_footer', 'add_class_to_textarea');

    function textarea_to_rte() {
      if(is_admin()) {
        $js_src = includes_url('js/tinymce/') . 'tinymce.min.js';
        $css_src = includes_url('css/') . 'editor.css';

        // wp_enqueue doesn't seem to work at all
        echo '<script src="' . $js_src . '" type="text/javascript"></script>';

        wp_register_style('tinymce_css', $css_src);
        wp_enqueue_style('tinymce_css');
      }
    }
    add_action('admin_head', 'textarea_to_rte');
```

I've looked for hours to try resolve the issue, trying different versions and methods but can't seem to solve the issue, could anyone help?

Here's the error(s) from chrome:

```
      Uncaught TypeError: c is not a function
      S.init @ tinymce.min.js:9
      (anonymous function) @ tinymce.min.js:9
      (anonymous function) @ tinymce.min.js:4
      n @ tinymce.min.js:2
      p @ tinymce.min.js:4
      (anonymous function) @ tinymce.min.js:4
      i @ tinymce.min.js:4
```

Thanks, Harry.

Comment: Your piece of code works for me, so the problem is probably not inside the code excerpt itself. You could try replacing the minified TinyMCE with a non-minified one in hope of a clearer error message.

Comment: Could you let me know what version of TinyMCE you're using? Thanks.

Comment: Works with 4.3.3 (2016-01-14) as well.

Comment: Hm, I am using 4.3.3. Can't see why it isn't working...

Comment: Did you try with `tinymce.js`? Does the error message look any different?

Comment: That doesn't seem to exist. I'm using the version that comes with WordPress (as it has the extra plugins that make it work with the WordPress features)

Comment: I don't think that the version in Wordpress has any Wordpress-specific tweaks, so you can use the unminified version that is available on the TinyMCE website.

Comment: I did have a go at doing this but there was some missing parts that looked WP specific and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: For testing 4.3.3, I used the version available on the TinyMCE website and it worked. So, I guess that the "missing parts" are somehow the reason to your problem.